# confusion in RC circuit regarding initial conditions and capacitor voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, dc, transient

[image]

Actually i was practicing circuit analysis with Differential Equations. This question has some confusing parts like-

1. In Steady State, **t<0** switch is still open the **10mF** capacitor is Charged to 5V and 0A current flows through it, now if a **8mF** Uncharged capacitor(0V) is connected at time t=0 as show in picture then What will be Node voltage **v(t)** or voltage across both capacitors as they both are in parallel is it 0v or 5v? Because if the voltage at node A for **t>0** is at 5v that means **8mF** Cap. charged instantaneously and if the node voltage becomes same as the uncharged cap i.e. 0v then also 10mF cap goes from 5 to 0. someone please clarify
2. There are two Initial Conditions, for 10mF **v(0⁻) = 5v** and for 8mF **v(0⁻) = 0v**, and the Variable is v(t), so value should i put in the end ? and i m getting different voltage expression for each initial condition. here's my work

$$\Rightarrow \dfrac{v\left( t\right) }{8}+10m\cdot \dfrac{dv\left( t\right) }{dt}+8m\cdot\dfrac{dv\left( t\right) }{dt}-\dfrac{5}{8}=0 ,\hspace{1cm} By \space KCL$$
$$\Rightarrow 18m\dfrac{dv\left( t\right) }{dt}+\dfrac{v}{8}=\dfrac{5}{8}$$
$$v\left( t\right) =A⋅e^{\dfrac{-t}{144⋅10^{-3}}}+5$$

It would we be really helpful for me if someone will give me some hints or physical reasoning or teach me how to handle these types of circuit situation **instead of Direct Answer**.

Comment: (1) it's indeterminate due to infinite current flow

Comment: This circuit can not be solved analytically because it violates our definitions of how capacitors behave and the meaning of parallel circuits. Connecting two ideal capacitors in parallel when they have different initial voltages requires infinite current for zero time.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Sir, could you please explain the this line "requires infinite current for zero time", what does it means ?

Comment: @Andyaka, sir could you please elaborate it little bit ? and also is it solvable, Means can we find expression for i(t) and v(t) ?

Comment: The current through a capacitor is proportional to the derivative of the voltage across it. What happens to the voltages across two capacitors that initially have different voltages and then you connect them in parallel. What is \$dV/dt\$ in this case?

Comment: Although the ideal case requires infinite current for an infinitesimal amount of time, the result of the charge distribution is the same (but with no resistive loss).  The analysis is possible.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson $i=C⋅dV/dt$, and sudden change in voltage leads to infinite current right ?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis how ?

Comment: Just like Ilya explains in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting infinite instanteneous current between caps aside, the question is probably about charge redistributing between the two capacitors. So the question is really like "here is 5V cap of 10mF, how does the charge redistribute if we attach another 8mF cap to it.

We want to find total charge on capacitor C1, which will be the same as total charge on capacitors C1 and C2 once C2 is connected.

The formula for it says Q = C x V.

Two capacitors in parallel is just one larger capacitor. Which will have the same total charge as before.

C1 x V1 = Q = (C1 + C2) x V2

I hope it's obvious why voltage on two caps is the same when they're connected in parallel.

This charge distribution is valid strictly for time moment t=0, at t>0 the capacitors will be gaining extra charge via the resistor, where you have a typical RC-circuit, simply with starting condition that the capacitor is not at 0V. It will charge from V2 to 5V eventually. But I don't see explicit question about t>0, only about t=0.

Edit: perfect components, perfect connections assumed. "Spherical capacitors in a vacuum"

Comment: ok so for t>0 how should i proceed? find differential equation by Kcl then solve it and the what condition should i apply ? please help

Comment: @fpsshubham it's simple RC circuit with IC formulae you can find anywhere. Remember that voltage is relative. Charging from 0V to 5V is IDENTICAL to the last letter and digit to charging from 995V to 1000V and from -34V to -29V. In this case, when at t=0 voltage on caps immediately drops, you will have a classic RC circuit with capacitor(s) charging from V2 to 5V.

Comment: Here you can find detailed explanation as well as the formula: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html Remember to adjust for charging not from 0 to 5V, but from V2 to 5V.

Comment: ok i'll give it a try!

Comment: Let me know what your V2 is and how you apply the RC formula. I did some napkin math.

Comment: to be honest i m new in this circuit analysis i m reading your comment again and again to understand properly and trying to solve the circuit... lol

Comment: for t>0 the node voltage stablizes and both capacitor will be on same potential right ?

Comment: parallel capacitors will always have the same potential(=voltage). From t=0 onwards. But since the charge of C1 will be now on C1 and C2, the voltage on C1 will drop at t=0 when C2 is connected. So now both capacitors willl be charging again for t>0. Here is a video about it (and yes there is my comment under the vid from when I was learning this stuff), hope this helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v0YlultV0w

Comment: i will definitely take a look into it. meanwhile here what i m getting for t>0 i m getting $$ v\left( t\right) =5-5⋅e^{\dfrac{-t}{144⋅10^{-3}}} $$ and $$ t \neq 0 $$

Comment: @fpsshubham ot only works if you're charging capacitor from 0V to 5V. But you're charging it not from 0V. You forgot to offset everything by V2 (voltage of capacitors from which charging to 5V starts).

Comment: this V2, will obtained as you described in your answer right ? So V2 = 50mC/18mF so V2 = 25/9 then $$v\left( t\right) =5-\dfrac{20}{9}⋅e^{\dfrac{-t}{144⋅10^{-3}}}$$

Comment: I ran spice simulation and as you told the V2 was $$\dfrac{20}{9}$$ at t=0. I really appreciate your help i learnt something new.